# How to acces other ui files in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How can I acces other ui files from code using Qt Creator?
I am trying to create a small text editor. As always, I designed the main window by pressing on the Design button . After that , I created a new ui file from Qt creator called about.ui (the IDE also added about.h and about.cpp ). The main window's functions(like on_button_cliked() ) are in the file textedit.cpp

I created a small menu with an about entry, and then I went to Action Editor ,I selected the entry , Go to Slot, and the trigerred();
The IDE created all the things for me, so all I need is to define the function.
How can I acces the about ui that I created earlier?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the access to the '.ui' file. Qt's `ui` application does everything for you. All you need now is to create an object of your `About` class with `MainWindow` as a parent and show it.

The approximate code will be:

```
#include "about.h"

// ...

void MainWindow::on_about_triggered()
{
    About dialog(this);
    dialog.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but when I click the About menu nothing happens code: void TextEditor::on_actionAbout_triggered()
{
    About dialog(this);
    dialog.exec();
}

Comment: Haven you renamed your about action? You could try to connect directly in a constructor like this: `connect(actionAbout, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(on_actionAbout_triggered()));`